# How can I exclude containers to remove with docker-compose down?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I call docker-compose down, I would like to exclude some containers.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can see the options here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/. You'll have to do this yourself.

Comment: You can use `docker-compose kill` to stop desired containers, leaving the others running.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `docker-compose kill <service name>` and `docker compose rm <service name>`.

Those two commands let you stop and delete just the wanted containers and leave the others running.